# How can I position two div elements side by side inside another one?

Tags: html, css

I would like `div#alpha1` and `div#alpha2` inside the `div#alpha` placed side by side.

**CODE**

```css
#alpha {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  width: 96%;
  height: 100px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
}
#alpha1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 94px;
  height: 94px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
#alpha2 {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  border-top: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 94px;
}
```

```html
<DIV id="alpha">
  <DIV id="alpha1">
    <IMG src="img/jenny.jpg" width="94px" height="94px">
  </DIV>
  <DIV id="alpha2">
    <H1 id="patientname">Jenny Thomas</H1>
  </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: Display:inline-block;

Answer (score 3):

you can use `flexbox` for that by using `display:flex` in parent and then `flex:1` in `#alpha2` to make it grow according to screen size

Don't use HTML `width`/`height` tags, instead use CSS for styling it.

**Note** I did a few tweaks to your code.

```css
#alpha {
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin: 8px 2% 0;
  width: 96%;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  display: flex
}
#alpha1 {
  width: 94px;
  height: 94px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 2%;
}
#alpha2 {
  flex: 1
}
#alpha2 h1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  height: 40px
}
```

```html
<div id="alpha">
  <div id="alpha1">
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/94/94" />
  </div>
  <div id="alpha2">
    <h1 id="patientname">Jenny Thomas</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest/fastest solution is to assign `display: flex` to the container `#alpha`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPgaJP

(I also erased some unneccesary settings in there)

Answer (score -1):

You just needed to set the float property of your div. Here you are :-

```css
#alpha{
    position:relative;
    padding-top:4px;
    margin-top:8px;
    margin-left:2%;
    margin-right:2%;
    width:96%;
    height:100px;
    border-top:1px solid black;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    float: none;
    }

#alpha1{
    position:relative;
    width:94px;
    height:94px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-left:2%;
    margin-right: 0px;
    float: left;
}
#alpha2{
    position:relative;
    margin-top:0px;
    height:40px;
    border-top:1px;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    margin-left:9%;
    float: next;
}
```

```html
<DIV id="alpha">
    <DIV id="alpha1">
        <IMG src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTvU-f_zys67Kv6hdqJcmSN5n_dfe2igiq9lLZYpcXAyVXEBNQ6" width="94" height="94" alt="IMAGE">
    </DIV>
    <DIV id="alpha2">
        <H1 id="patientname">Jenny Thomas</H1>
    </DIV>
    </DIV>
```

I edited your margin in alpha2 for correct display of bottom line. It is displayed correct in browser. Here it is not. You can check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5ka3bg7g/). Mark the problem solved if it helps.

Comment: there is no `float:next` your comment in `width:calc()` is invalid for CSS, and you stated in comments to question that `inline-block` would do nothing here, really?

Comment: @dippas: Yes. I am firm on my answer. And float next and none,and width calc  are also valid options. If you do not know about them its not my fault. From where you learned css anyway ? Regarding display inline block, run it and check it.

Comment: `float:next` is valid?? check valid values  for float [here in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float), I didn't say `calc()` was invalid, I did say your comments before `width:calc()`, this `//` are CSS invalid comments. and finally I can make an answer with that HTML  using `inline-block`, so yes it is a valid option

Comment: @dippas:    In your answer, you used flex. Without it alone inline block can not do anything. I used float. We used two different techniques to get same result. And again, float next is valid. Learn css first. And I can also down vote.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, And again I said I could make an answer with `inline-block`, I used `flexbox` because in this case it  there is less code

Comment: You shouldn't downvote just for vengeance and even more based on assumption that the user who's commenting your answer downvote your answer

Comment: @dippas: Why were you commenting if you did not down vote my answer. I'll up vote you. Happy...............

Comment: Because I was just trying to let you know the reason that might let you get downvoted,

Comment: Sorry. I thought you down voted my answer. I was very angry. I put great effort in my each answer. I tried to upvote you but its not accepting. Extremely Sorry again.

Comment: @dippas: undone my down vote. Thanks for everything.